# Why W_q matrix in torch.nn.MultiheadAttention is quadratic

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, pytorch, torch, attention-model

I am trying to implement nn.MultiheadAttention in my network. According to the [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.MultiheadAttention.html),

> **embed_dim**  – total dimension of the model.

However, according to the [source file](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/activation.html#MultiheadAttention),

> embed_dim must be divisible by num_heads

and

> self.q_proj_weight = Parameter(torch.Tensor(embed_dim, embed_dim))

If I understand properly, this means each head takes **only a part of features of each query**, as the matrix is quadratic. Is it a bug of realization or is my understanding wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each head uses a different part of the projected query vector. You can imagine it as if the query gets split into `num_heads` vectors that are independently used to compute the scaled dot-product attention. So, each head operates on a different linear combination of the features in queries (and keys and values, too). This linear projection is done using the `self.q_proj_weight` matrix and the projected queries are passed to `F.multi_head_attention_forward` function.

In [`F.multi_head_attention_forward`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/functional.py#L4091), it is implemented by reshaping and transposing the query vector, so that the independent attentions for individual heads can be computed [efficiently by matrix multiplication](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/functional.py#L4122).

The attention head sizes are a design decision of PyTorch. In theory, you could have a different head size, so the projection matrix would have a shape of `embedding_dim` × `num_heads * head_dims`. Some implementations of transformers (such as C++-based [Marian](https://github.com/marian-nmt/marian) for machine translation, or [Huggingface's Transformers](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers)) allow that.

Comment: Thank you! Still, the question was slightly different: in torch realization I can only see multiplication by matrix of shape (`embed_dim x embed_dim`), hence is it true that when I input Q, each head will operate with *a subset of features* of the matrix Q?

Comment: Intuitively, you can say that; technically it is correct to say that each attention head operates on a linear combination of the features.